# Difference between `/inbox/unread` & `/me/inbox/unread`

Tags: support, api-v2.2, documentation, inbox

I ran [/inbox/unread](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread) & [/me/inbox/unread](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-unread-inbox).

What is the difference between the two? Also, the `site` parameter which we give in call to `/me/inbox/unread` is not required as [inbox_item](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item) refers to [global inbox](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox). Another reason is it is giving wrong results.

I gave `programmers` as `site` parameter in call to `/me/inbox/unread`, and I am getting all the unread inbox items, even though I didn't post any question to [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/186801/amit-jha?tab=questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference and...
The inbox has always been ["The global inbox"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/global-inbox/info). Certainly for as long as the API has existed.

So any inbox route will be Stack Exchange wide, even if it accepts a `site` parameter.  If you look at the doc for [the `/users/{id}/inbox/unread` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-unread-inbox), it says:

> This method is effectively an alias for /inbox/unread. It is provided for consumers who make strong assumptions about operating within the context of a single site rather than the Stack Exchange network as a whole.

It's not too clear what good purpose that serves.  Maybe it's for developers who feel naked unless they send a `site` parameter?    (Except IIRC, extra parameters are generally ignored?)

Also, for almost every `/users/{id}/xxx` route, there is a convenient shorthand `/me/xxx` route -- where the user ID is taken to be the already authenticated user.

So we have:

- `/inbox/unread` ~==~ `/users/{id}/inbox/unread` by "alias"
- `/users/{id}/inbox/unread` ~==~ `/me/inbox/unread` by shorthand
- So, `/inbox/unread` ~==~ `/me/inbox/unread`

Irregardless, they are de facto the same and have been since their introduction in API-2.0.

Comment: Very complex. No need to have two functions for the same purpose without any reason. `site` parameter has no purpose.

Comment: I agree.  At the very least, the docs should be clearer about why there are 2 duplicate functions.